# Linux + how to create simple Progress Bar in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, graphics

I want to add a progress bar in my bash script that show the "." character as progress , and process ended after MAX 180 second

in the bash script I use curl command , so curl give the results after sometime but not greater then 180 sec

something like that

```
|.                                           after 2 sec
|...........                                 after 60 sec
|...................                         after 100 sec
|..........................                  after 150 sec
|................................|           after 180 sec
```

final example

```
|................................|       after 180 sec
```

or

```
|....|                                   after 30 sec
```

Comment: You may use or adapt from this one  https://github.com/noqqe/bash-progress-bar if it can help you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is rather simple to do in just plain Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
# progress bar function
prog() {
    local w=80 p=$1;  shift
    # create a string of spaces, then change them to dots
    printf -v dots "%*s" "$(( $p*$w/100 ))" ""; dots=${dots// /.};
    # print those dots on a fixed-width space plus the percentage etc. 
    printf "\r\e[K|%-*s| %3d %% %s" "$w" "$dots" "$p" "$*"; 
}
# test loop
for x in {1..100} ; do
    prog "$x" still working...
    sleep .1   # do some work here
done ; echo
```

The first argument to `prog` is the percentage, any others are printed after the progress bar. The variable `w` in the function controls the width of the bar. Print a newline after you're done, the function doesn't print one.

---

Another possibility would be to use the `pv` tool. It's meant for measuring the throughput of a pipeline, but we can create one for it:

```
for x in {1..100} ; do
    sleep .1    # do some work here
    printf .
done | pv -pt -i0.2 -s100 -w 80 > /dev/null
```

Here, `-pt` enables the progress bar and the timer, `-s 100` sets the total output size, and whatever we print inside the function counts against that size.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can implement this by overwriting a line. Use `\r` to go back to the beginning of the line without writing `\n` to the terminal.

Write `\n` when you're done to advance the line.

Use `echo -ne` to:

- not print `\n` and
- to recognize escape sequences like `\r.`

Here's a demo:

```
echo -ne '...                     (33%)\r'
sleep 1
echo -ne '......                  (66%)\r'
sleep 1
echo -ne '..........              (100%)\r'
echo -ne '\n'
```

EDIT: Now, cURL comes with a progress bar: `--progress-bar`, is that not what you want ?

taken from answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238073/how-to-add-a-progress-bar-to-a-shell-script

Found that with Google, first answer, with the following search terms: "bash progress bar"